# How to capture shell output to text file?

Tags: command-line, windows-8

In linux I can type in `echo "hello" >& text.output` and get text output in a file.

How can I get this kind of output in Windows 8?

Is there a way to tell error from output?

My motivation is trying to log the output of `tracert` and investigate difference between Windows 8 and Windows 7.

Comment: What is `72162`?

Comment: That was a typo...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/99066/windows-command-prompt-how-to-keep-all-of-the-output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way as in Linux:

```
echo "Hello" >text.output
```

Errors usually printed to `stderr` stream (it is #2). You can capture `stderr` stream:

```
del 1.txt 2>text.output
```

If the file `1.txt` does not exist, `text.output` will contain `Could not find 1.txt`.

---

You can redirect `stdout` to `stderr`:

```
echo "Hello" 2>&1
```

Or `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
echo "Hello" 1>&2
```

---

P.S. I'm not sure your command would work in Linux. Anyway `echo "hello" >& text.output` generates a syntax error: `>& was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: It works on Gentoo and SLES. It might not be very strict POSIX.

Comment: [Little-known feature: The redirection operator can go anywhere on the line.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225630/how-to-echo-2-no-quotes-to-a-file-from-a-batch-script)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Haven't known about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The shell in Windows now is very similar with BASH on Linux.
So you can just do

```
echo "Hello" > text.txt
```

Or, run your program, and let the system output write to `text.txt`:

```
run_program > text.txt
```

If you need to track the error, use the following:

```
run_program 2> error.txt
```

More information and examples could be found here. [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)